# Составление запроса для двух таблиц

Tags: sql

Делаю анализатор чата со статистикой по используемым матерным словам и соответствующим рейтингом.

Структуры таблиц:

Messages:
id - уникальный ID сообщения, from_id — ID отправителя, date — дата отправки, text — текст.

Offensive:

id — уникальный ID мата, найденого в сообщении, type — числовое значение, ассоциированное с корнем матерного слова, from_id — ID отправителя (тот же, что и в Messages), in_message — ID сообщения, в котором употреблен этот мат, text — сам мат.

Далее я следующим запросом строил рейтинг матершинников:

`` SELECT from_id, COUNT(*) FROM `Offensive` GROUP BY from_id ORDER BY `COUNT(*)` DESC ``

Однако читеры начали писать сообщения вида «бля бля бля бля бля» и накручивать себе рейтинг. Я думаю, что подобное читерство можно отсеять, если строить рейтинг запросом, не учитывающим больше определенного количества матов в N-ный промежуток времени, но, к сожалению, ума не приложу, как это сделать...

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Просто введи разумный предел частоты. И тех, кто его превысил, просто выбрасывай из этого "рейтинга". Навсегда, навечно. Нет для пиписькомера хуже наказания, чем полный игнор.

Comment: @Akina, ну так не интересно